# Why won't this IPP QBO v3 API request set this Account object's SubAccount attribute to false?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Using [this page](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/account) of the documentation as a guide, I'm trying to make this account *no longer* be a sub-account (for the time-being, by using [the API explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Account)):

```
{
    "Name": "Accumulated Depreciation",
    "ParentRef": {
        "value" :  null
    },
    "sparse": true,
    "Id": "4",
    "SyncToken": "2"
}
```

I've also tried it by explicitly setting the attribute to false (both with *and* without the ParentRef attribute update).

Here's with:

```
{
    "Name": "Accumulated Depreciation",
    "ParentRef": {
        "value" :  null
    },
    "SubAccount": false,
    "sparse": true,
    "Id": "4",
    "SyncToken": "2"
}
```

Here's without:

```
{
    "Name": "Accumulated Depreciation",
    "SubAccount": false,
    "sparse": true,
    "Id": "4",
    "SyncToken": "2"
}
```

I get no error, but the fact that the response still shows the account as a sub of 65 indicates that the update isn't working:

```
{
  "Account": {
    "Name": "Accumulated Depreciation",
    "SubAccount": true,
    "ParentRef": {
      "value": "65"
    },
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Computer Hardware:Accumulated Depreciation",
    "Active": true,
    "Classification": "Asset",
    "AccountType": "Fixed Asset",
    "AccountSubType": "OtherFixedAssets",
    "CurrentBalance": 0,
    "CurrentBalanceWithSubAccounts": 0,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "4",
    "SyncToken": "2",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-03-09T07:48:23-07:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-03-09T11:17:48-07:00"
    }
  },
  "time": "2014-03-09T11:23:30.36-07:00"
}
```

Do you know what I'm missing?

Thank you!

[UPDATE AFTER MANAS'S RESPONSE:]

I'm trying it with the full update without success. Here are the bodies of the two requests I've tried:

```
{
    "Name": "Accumulated Depreciation",
    "SubAccount": false,
    "ParentRef": {
      "value": null
    },
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Accumulated Depreciation",
    "Active": true,
    "Classification": "Asset",
    "AccountType": "Fixed Asset",
    "AccountSubType": "OtherFixedAssets",
    "CurrentBalance": 0,
    "CurrentBalanceWithSubAccounts": 0,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "4",
    "SyncToken": "2",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-03-09T07:48:23-07:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-03-09T11:17:48-07:00"
    }
}
```

and...

```
{
    "Name": "Accumulated Depreciation",
    "SubAccount": false,
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Accumulated Depreciation",
    "Active": true,
    "Classification": "Asset",
    "AccountType": "Fixed Asset",
    "AccountSubType": "OtherFixedAssets",
    "CurrentBalance": 0,
    "CurrentBalanceWithSubAccounts": 0,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "4",
    "SyncToken": "2",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-03-09T07:48:23-07:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-03-09T11:17:48-07:00"
    }
}
```

(I also tried it with the USD currency block below in Manas's response, just for kicks. Nothing changed.)

In both cases nothing happens, and the response remains what I have above.

Answer (score -1):

Sparse update is not supported for account entity.

Please try full update. It will work.

I had created a sub account from UI and retrieved it as a sub and non-sub ( by making changes in UI).. and here are the two responses.

**Sub-Account**

```
{
   "Account":{
      "Name":"TEST_SUB_ACCNT",
      "SubAccount":true,
      "ParentRef":{
         "value":"54"
      },
      "Description":"Sub Account",
      "FullyQualifiedName":"TEST_PARENT_ACCNT:TEST_SUB_ACCNT",
      "Active":true,
      "Classification":"Asset",
      "AccountType":"Bank",
      "AccountSubType":"Savings",
      "CurrentBalance":200.0,
      "CurrentBalanceWithSubAccounts":200.0,
      "CurrencyRef":{
         "value":"USD",
         "name":"United States Dollar"
      },
      "domain":"QBO",
      "sparse":false,
      "Id":"55",
      "SyncToken":"0",
      "MetaData":{
         "CreateTime":"2014-03-09T12:16:11-07:00",
         "LastUpdatedTime":"2014-03-09T12:16:11-07:00"
      }
   },
   "time":"2014-03-09T12:19:16.669-07:00"
}
```

**Non-sub account**

```
{
   "Account":{
      "Name":"TEST_SUB_ACCNT",
      "SubAccount":false,
      "Description":"Sub Account",
      "FullyQualifiedName":"TEST_SUB_ACCNT",
      "Active":true,
      "Classification":"Asset",
      "AccountType":"Bank",
      "AccountSubType":"Savings",
      "CurrentBalance":200.0,
      "CurrentBalanceWithSubAccounts":200.0,
      "CurrencyRef":{
         "value":"USD",
         "name":"United States Dollar"
      },
      "domain":"QBO",
      "sparse":false,
      "Id":"55",
      "SyncToken":"1",
      "MetaData":{
         "CreateTime":"2014-03-09T12:16:11-07:00",
         "LastUpdatedTime":"2014-03-09T12:20:19-07:00"
      }
   },
   "time":"2014-03-09T12:20:38.342-07:00"
}
```

**Update request generated using devkit** (didn't work)

```
{ "AccountSubType" : "Savings",
  "AccountType" : "Bank",
  "Active" : true,
  "Classification" : "Asset",
  "CurrencyRef" : { "name" : "United States Dollar",
      "value" : "USD"
    },
  "CurrentBalance" : 200.0,
  "CurrentBalanceWithSubAccounts" : 200.0,
  "Description" : "Sub Account",
  "FullyQualifiedName" : "TEST_PARENT_ACCNT:TEST_SUB_ACCNT",
  "Id" : "55",
  "MetaData" : { "CreateTime" : "2014-03-10T00:46:11+05:30",
      "LastUpdatedTime" : "2014-03-10T10:16:15+05:30"
    },
  "Name" : "TEST_SUB_ACCNT",
  "SubAccount" : false,
  "SyncToken" : "2",
  "domain" : "QBO",
  "sparse" : false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Manas, I'm trying the full update (and have modified my response to that effect). Still no dice. Would you mind pasting the update request body in here so I can see what might be missing in mine? Thank you!

Comment: Hi HaPsantran, I tried it using devkit but as you have mentioned the sub account it not getting changed to a parent account. It looks like a bug. I'll raise a bug for this and update this post. I've pasted the post request boy in my original post. Thanks

Comment: It is an issue in service. I'll update this post mentioning release date and version number. Thanks

Comment: Does that mean we'll be able to track when the issue is addressed? Is there an ETA you can share with us?

Comment: The fix of this issue has not been prioritized yet. But it will be fixed asap. You can see this has been mentioned in the following page - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_v2_to_v3_migration_known_issues . I'll update this post as soon as I get any info on this.

Comment: Manas, it looks like the API page has been updated. Do I correctly surmise that the issue will not be fixed anytime soon? It's gone from the pending list and just shows up in [known issues] (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_v3_known_issues). Thank you.